# Connection Property in EF5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

Am trying to establish SQL connection using Entityframework Connection  and i got the beow code in google

```
((EntityConnection)dataContext.Connection).StoreConnection;
```

But am not able to get the Connection property.It is not available and thought some changes would have happened in EF5 similar to the below code and posting my clarification here.

```
dataContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled
```

In EF5

```
dataContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled
```

How do i get the connection Property in EF5 ? Or am i missing anything !

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The options on how we access has changed in EF5.

Here is the sample

```
var sConnection = ((dataContext)ctx.Database.Connection);
```

The above code will return as the SQL Connection property.

Hope this helps some one :)